# Add Contacts Button Missing - Salesforce Marketing Cloud Contact Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud

I want to manually add contacts in Marketing Cloud Contact Builder, however I don't see an Add Contacts button anywhere.

When I load up the All Contacts tab an Add Contacts button shows up but then disappears as the page finishes loading...

I have all permissions so not sure why I can't see anything, is there another way to manually add contacts that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

The contacts in Marketing Cloud are created based on the channel to which they belong.
So in order to create a contact, you would want to define which channel it comes from.

I put the way to add contacts in these channels here for your reference:

Email channel: [Add a Subscriber Manually](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=sf.mc_es_add_subscriber_manually.htm&type=5)

Mobile channel: [Create Contacts Manually](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_moc_create_contacts_manually.htm&type=5)

Push channel: [Import contact to Mobile Push](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_mp_import_contacts_to_a_standard_list_or_into_all_contacts.htm&type=5)